# How to catch barcode-scanner?

Tags: vb.net, barcode-scanner

I am creating a system that when the user uses the barcode scanner, it will automatically fill into a specific field. 
Example: The cursor is in the `textfield4`, when I click the barcode scanner, the input should be placed in `textfield1`.
Thanks in advance for the help.

I have downloaded the SDK but I'm having a compatibility issue. I am using symbol barcode scanner LS2208. The SDK Provided by motorola isn't working.

I tried catching the time of input when enter is pressed. 1st scan is good, after that it leaves out the 1st few characters behind.

Comment: Barcode scanners normally just pump the characters into the keyboard buffer - you can't easily tell it apart from normal keyboard input.

Comment: any suggestions on how to solve this problem?